# color isn't being added to the first span

Tags: html, css

Color should be applied to the data-words, however it is only applying to the cursor. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```html
<h2 class="hero__title h1"> Your<span class="typer" id="main" data-words="living room.,,bathroom.,,dining room.," style="color:blue" data-delay="100" data-deleteDelay="1000"></span>
<span class="cursor" data-owner="main" style="color:#F47268"></span><br>Reborn
</h2>

<script async src="https://unpkg.com/typer-dot-js@0.1.0/typer.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider `data-colors` where you can specify a different color per word or one color that will apply to all:

```html
<h2 class="hero__title h1"> Your <span class="typer" id="main" data-words="living room.,,bathroom.,,dining room.," data-colors="blue,green,red" data-delay="100" data-deleteDelay="1000"></span>
<span class="cursor" data-owner="main" style="color:#F47268"></span><br>Reborn
</h2>

<script async src="https://unpkg.com/typer-dot-js@0.1.0/typer.js"></script>
```

Reference: https://steven.codes/typerjs/docs/index.html#class-typer

Comment: Works nice but change the cursor color by style="color:#F47268" since the data-colors doesnt work on cursor

Comment: Any idea how to use a comma "," without it being a delimmiter?  I have tried the ascii code <span>&#44;</span>. Not working

Comment: @bradwalls in this case, change the delimiter to another  character to be able to use the comma inside text. Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/p7e0Lgdm/

Answer (score 1):

In your head tag, try this:

```
<style>
  span.typer {
    color: blue !important;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data-colors attribute. It is in the [documentation](https://steven.codes/typerjs/playground.html)

```
<h2 class="hero__title h1"> Your <span class="typer" id="main" data-words="living room.,,bathroom.,,dining room.," style="color:blue" data-delay="100" data-deleteDelay="1000" data-colors="blue"></span>
<span class="cursor" data-owner="main" style="color:#F47268"></span><br>Reborn
</h2>

<script async src="https://unpkg.com/typer-dot-js@0.1.0/typer.js"></script>
```